# How to add additional urls created manually in scrapy python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy Python to crawl a website and extract some information from certain pages. Some pages have ID numbers throughout the content that I am able to grab but that do not show up as real URL for the spider. I am able to find them manually and build the url using the ID but how to I send them to the spider to crawl?

**In the function parse_product_abc below I am able to get a bunch of itemids. If I loop through them, I can build new urls to scrape. How can I tell the spider to crawl them?**

```
class AbcSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "abc"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            # follow category pages
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=[r'/cat/abc.+/C\-abc.{6,14}$'],
                deny=('-something1-','-something2-','-something3-')
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback='parse_category_abc'
        ),
        Rule(
            # parse product pages
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=[r'/prd/[A-z0-9\-]+/\d{9}$'],
                deny=('-something1-','-something2-','-something3-')
                )
            ),
            follow=False,
            callback='parse_product_abc'
        )
    )
    def parse_product_abc(self, response):
        # grab json array from html
        product_json = response.xpath('//body').re_first(r'ABC\.PID\.Data\((.*)\);')
        product_obj  = json.loads(product_json)
        itemId       = product_obj['itemId']
        item = AbcItem()
        item['abc_itemId'] = int(itemId)
        item['abc_item']   = product_obj
        item['abc_url']   = response.url
        item['time']   = datetime.datetime.now()
        item['spider'] = self.name
        # find more data-pid attributes in html...
        itemids = response.xpath('//@data-pid').extract()
        # connect to mongo and see if new item found or not...
        connection = MongoClient(self.settings.get('MONGO_URI'))
        db = connection.abc_data
        if db['products_abc'].find_one({"abc_itemId":int(itemId)}):
            # duplicate item
            print ' '
            print 'DUP: %s' % itemId
            print 'DUP: %s' % item['abc_url']
        else:
            # new item found
            print ' '
            print 'NEW: %s' % itemId
            print 'NEW: %s' % item['abc_url']
            yield item
    def parse_category_abc(self, response):
        print 'CATEGORY: %s' % response.url
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Import **Request** class:

   ```
   from scrapy.http import Request
   ```

> Let's imagine that http://foo.bar/items/45653 is a product/item URL,
>   being **45653** the product/item id

2. Loop through those product/item ids and generate a URL for each one of them, then yield a Request to each URL with a callback to some parse method:

   ```
   for pid in response.xpath('//@data-pid').extract():
       url = "http://foo.bar/items/{}".format(pid)
       yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_product_abc)
   ```

> I don't know if you'll use `self.parse_product_abc` or another method as the callback, but that's the way you could do it.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped @KyleAnderson. Have a nice weekend.